# Как совместить типы int и rune в golang

Tags: golang, указатели, типы-данных

Недавно писал код на Go и решил реализовать заполнение массива через указатели:

```
func PutARR(a *rune) {
    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        var h rune
        fmt.Scanf("%c", &h)
        *(a + i) = h
    }
}
```

Пишет нельзя совмещать разные типы (оно и понятно). Прошу, помогите как грамотнее будет реализовать данную функцию.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь писать на go как на си. А Go не поддерживает арифметику указателей для обычных указателей. К тому же я не уверен, что `a` содержит достаточно места. Что именно Вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Я пытался заполнить массив используя функцию с указателями

Comment: Переформулирую свой вопрос, что именно Вы пытаетесь сделать?  Если используете массив, то и пишите массив. В golang массивы и указатели немного разные вещи.

Comment: На языке C++ я реализовал функцию:
```
void putARR(unsigned char *a){
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      *(a + i) = getchar();
}
```
Где заполнил массив при помощи её. Однако я учусь сразу на 3 языках: C++, Python и Go; и решил сделать такую же фичу и на ГО, но не знал, что он просто не поддерживает арифметику указателей. И теперь сомневаюсь, что это была здравая идея...

Comment: хочу Вас разочаровать - Вы похоже учите си. Плюс код очень печален - размер массива приходит где то с другого места - проблем будет куча. В разных языках разные парадигмы. И не нужно их тащить с одного языка в другой. И не нужно писать `*(a + i) `, пишите явно `a[i]` - эффективность такая же, а читабельность в разы лучше